# what this code mean in wcf

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, asp.net-ajax

when we use `WCF` in asp we use `[ServiceContract]` and `[OperationContract]`.what it means.I search in google about this but unable to understand.plz help to clear my vision about this.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These attributes helps the framework to expose the respective class/operation (methods) as a service on web.

Basically WCF gives you a flexibility of saying which classes/methods, etc. you want to expose on web as a service and which not. Thus these attributes do come in handy here.

If you rem when doing Nunit test cases, you write [TextFixture] for test cases because Nunit recognizes them that way.

Comment: well fast typing of mine makes this. Ill try to be better, thanks

Answer (score 1):

In WCF, all services expose contracts. The contract is a platform-neutral and standard way of describing what the service does.

`ServiceContract` - This attribute is used to define the Interface.

`OperationContract` - This attribute is used to define the method inside Interface.

```
 [ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(TestServiceCallback))]
    public interface TestService
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
        byte[] TestMethod(string testParam);
}
```

Here is the reference site:

http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/courses/tableofcontents?courseName=wcf-fundamentals

Answer (score 1):

WCF contract specifies what operations the service supports. An operation can be thought of as a Web service method. Service contracts define groups of operations.
You can see more about wcf contacts [here](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/interview/exam286-what-are-contracts-in-wcf-.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I seem to always have this problem as well. Microsoft will tell you to do it, and how to do it. But the reason for doing it remains a mystery and nobody will tell you. I guess it is just assumed that you know.

AFAIK these "Attributes" are simply a tag that perform no real actions. The compiler just finds the tag and understands the method below the tag to be a "ServiceContract" and from there it does it's own thing in relation to that specific method.